# Simple but stupid clickable area Flutter Issue

Tags: android, ios, flutter, image, dart

I have an issue with the main part of our app.

In my app, I have a mesh that is overlapped by images of the human body muscles. Currently, I have it so that there is a fractionally sized box surrounding each muscle. I want it so that when you click the muscle, it console.logs the muscle name, but right now it logs the muscle name when you click ANYWHERE INSIDE the black box. I only want it so that it prints when you click the muscle and NOT the entire box.

Here is an image showing what I mean:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Stack(children: [
                  Positioned(
                    //mesh
                    top: topPadding + size.height * .07,
                    child: Container(
                        width: size.width,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Container(
                                width: size.width,
                                height: height,
                                //color: Color.fromARGB(255, 86, 86, 86),
                                child: Transform.translate(
                                    offset: Offset(0, -10),
                                    child: InteractiveViewer(
                                        child: Stack(
                                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                                            children: [
                                          GestureDetector(
                                              onTap: () {
                                                print('Mesh Clicked');
                                              },
                                              child: Image.asset(
                                                  'assets/3d_model/Back_Side/mesh_back.png')),
                                          GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              print('Back Core Clicked');
                                            },
                                            child: Transform.translate(
                                              offset:
                                                  Offset(0, -(height) * .55),
                                              child: SizedBox(
                                                height: size.height.toDouble(),
                                                width: double.infinity,
                                                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                                                    alignment:
                                                        Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                                    heightFactor: 0.122,
                                                    child: Image.asset(
                                                        'assets/3d_model/Back_Side/core_b.png')),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              print('Back Forearms Clicked');
                                            },
                                            child: Transform.translate(
                                              offset:
                                                  Offset(0, -(height) * .498),
                                              child: SizedBox(
                                                height: size.height.toDouble(),
                                                width: double.infinity,
                                                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                                                    alignment:
                                                        Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                                    heightFactor: 0.15,
                                                    child: Container(
                                                        color: Colors
                                                            .black) /*Image.asset(
                                                        'assets/3d_model/Back_Side/forearms_b.png')*/
                                                    ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              print('Back Lats Clicked');
                                            },
                                            child: Transform.translate(
                                              offset:
                                                  Offset(0, -(height) * .612),
                                              child: SizedBox(
                                                height: size.height.toDouble(),
                                                width: double.infinity,
                                                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                                                    alignment:
                                                        Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                                    heightFactor: 0.148,
                                                    child: Image.asset(
                                                        'assets/3d_model/Back_Side/lats_b.png')),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              print('Upper Back Clicked');
                                            },
                                            child: Transform.translate(
                                              offset:
                                                  Offset(0, -(height) * .712),
                                              child: SizedBox(
                                                height: size.height.toDouble(),
                                                width: double.infinity,
                                                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                                                    alignment:
                                                        Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                                    heightFactor: 0.174,
                                                    child: Image.asset(
                                                        'assets/3d_model/Back_Side/upper_back_b.png')),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              print('Back Shoulders Clicked');
                                            },
                                            child: Transform.translate(
                                              offset:
                                                  Offset(0, -(height) * .747),
                                              child: SizedBox(
                                                height: size.height.toDouble(),
                                                width: double.infinity,
                                                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                                                    alignment:
                                                        Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                                    heightFactor: 0.073,
                                                    child: Image.asset(
                                                        'assets/3d_model/Back_Side/shoulders_b.png')),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              print('Back Triceps Clicked');
                                            },
                                            child: Transform.translate(
                                              offset:
                                                  Offset(0, -(height) * .69),
                                              child: SizedBox(
                                                height: size.height.toDouble(),
                                                width: double.infinity,
                                                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                                                    alignment:
                                                        Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                                    heightFactor: 0.043,
                                                    child: Image.asset(
                                                        'assets/3d_model/Back_Side/triceps_b.png')),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              print('Back Calves Clicked');
                                            },
                                            child: Transform.translate(
                                              offset:
                                                  Offset(0, -(height) * .04),
                                              child: SizedBox(
                                                height: size.height.toDouble(),
                                                width: double.infinity,
                                                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                                                    alignment:
                                                        Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                                    heightFactor: 0.26,
                                                    child: Image.asset(
                                                        'assets/3d_model/Back_Side/calves_b.png')),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              print('Back Upper Legs Clicked');
                                            },
                                            child: Transform.translate(
                                              offset:
                                                  Offset(0, -(height) * .275),
                                              child: SizedBox(
                                                height: size.height.toDouble(),
                                                width: double.infinity,
                                                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                                                    alignment:
                                                        Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                                    heightFactor: 0.305,
                                                    child: Image.asset(
                                                        'assets/3d_model/Back_Side/upper_legs_b.png')),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ])))))),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                      top: topPadding + size.height * .05,
                      right: size.width * .1,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              frontSide = true;
                            });
                          },
                          child: Container(
                              width: 60,
                              child: Row(children: [
                                Text('180°'),
                                Spacer(),
                                Icon(Icons.threesixty)
                              ]))))
                ])
```

Comment: instead of those multiple png files you can do that with one single svg file, more here:https://gist.github.com/pskink/afd4f20a40ae7756555877ec030daa46 - the most important part is `CountryBorder` class

Comment: Could you give an example with a lot less code that more direct?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pskink/afd4f20a40ae7756555877ec030daa46#file-world_map-dart-L117 - here `Material` uses `shape:` parameter that clips child `InkWell` in tap events - this is the most important part of that code